# Js: Get the percentage of the scroll on an image tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some images in my HTML page.
I want to do some animation on my images that start when the image is visible to the screen until is not.
So for that, I need the scroll percentage of the image.

Actually, I need to know how much of the image is scrolled by the user, to do some animation based on that percentage.

For better understanding, see the below images.
Start:
[image]

End:
[image]

How can I calc it with Javascript or jQuery on scroll?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a sample snippet that tracks if the image is in view and if it is the scrolling percentage of the image.

You can alter the example for your case but you should probably have to use window's scroll event and trigger your animations/events depending on the scroll percentage.

```js
var $element = $('#element');
var $win = $(window);
var $vis = $('#visible');

$win.on('scroll', function() {
  $vis.text(percentageSeen() + '%');
});

function percentageSeen() {
  var viewportHeight = $(window).height(),
    scrollTop = $win.scrollTop(),
    elementOffsetTop = $element.offset().top,
    elementHeight = $element.height();


  if (elementOffsetTop > (scrollTop + viewportHeight)) {
    return 0;
  } else if ((elementOffsetTop + elementHeight) < scrollTop) {
    return 100;
  } else {
    var distance = (scrollTop + viewportHeight) - elementOffsetTop;
    var percentage = distance / ((viewportHeight + elementHeight) / 100);
    percentage = Math.round(percentage);
    return percentage;
  }
}

$win.trigger('scroll');
```

```css
body {
  padding: 400px 200px;
  height: 1200px;
}

#visible {
  padding: 5px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="visible"></div>

<img id="element" width="300" height="300" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" />
```